# PHP rename failed for foldername with utf-8 turkish charset string

Tags: php, utf-8, file-rename

```
<?php

$oldname = 'D:\a\file.zip';
$newName = 'D:\a\öÖçÇ\İ\file.zip';
//$newName = 'D:\a\ooCC\i\file.zip'; it's work

rename($oldname, $newName);

?>
```

Error:

```
Warning: rename(D:\a\file.zip,D:\a\öÖçÇ\İ\file.zip): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in C:\Users\Desktop\rename.php on line 9
```

I tried "url_encode", "iconv" however didn't work it.

Comment: Just to confirm, the directory "D:\a\öÖçÇ\İ\" does already exist? Do you get the same problem if you just rename the file to have Turkish letters, rather than moving it into a directory that does, e.g. `rename("D:\a\file.zip", "D:\a\file-öÖçÇ-İ.zip");`?

Comment: yes, the folder directory exists. I have to use Turkish characters. I will integrate it into a system.

Comment: It's always been a mess, but if I recall correctly Windows doesn't use UTF-8 almost anywhere, let alone the file system, and PHP only uses the correct Win32 API in recent versions. I suggest you create a file manually, read its name from PHP and `bin2hex()` it to see what it looks like.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Good point. A lot of native Windows APIs were written to support early (16-bit) Unicode, and therefore adopted UTF-16 rather than the UTF-8 which became popular elsewhere.

Comment: You say you "tried iconv", can you show us what you tried exactly? Since iconv is a function for converting from one encoding to another, you can only use it effectively if you know what encoding you _have_, and what encoding you _want_.

Comment: iconv("UTF-8", "CP1252", $newNam);

Comment: [Code Page 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) doesn't have an encoding for "İ", so if the directory exists with that name, it can't be in that encoding. I don't have a Windows PHP installed to test it with, but `iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16", $newNam);` seems like a more likely guess (as mentioned above, a lot of Windows APIs use UTF-16 rather than UTF-8). Another possibility is that your PHP source file isn't in UTF-8, so you need to re-save it or use `iconv("some other encoding your text editor is using", "UTF-8", $newNam);`

Comment: [Your image](https://prnt.sc/1y9amd4) shows `$newName = 'D:/a/öÖçÇ/İ/file.zip';` with _forward slashes_. Use [backslash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#paths) instead. BTW, the answer by @Top-Master was right!

Comment: @JosefZ You can use either path separator. On Windows, PHP (and some Win32 APIs) support both.

Answer (score 1):

The file path needed to be encoded as UTF-16 for Windows to recognise it. Since my PHP source code is saved with encoding "UTF-8", I used this:

```
$oldname = 'D:\a\file.zip';
$newName = 'D:\a\öÖçÇ\İ\file.zip';
$newName = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16", $newName);

$copyIslem = copy($oldname, $newName);
```

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. I've added a bit of extra explanation which might help future readers of this question.

Comment: Utterly absurd. Here `iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16", $newName);` line is completely unavailing as the [`iconv` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) does not change the string to be converted (`$newName` in this particular case).

Comment: @JosefZ Huh, I didn't notice that. Possibly the actual fix was $newName = iconv... but they made a mistake copying here?

Comment: @IMSoP Of course, you can check yourself that `echo iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16", $newName);` gives total gibberish…

Comment: @JosefZ Well, it gives UTF-16, so if you try to display it as UTF-8, it will look like gibberish; but that's not what the question is about.